# QR code gone empty while printing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code

i generated `qr code` using this command in ruby on rails.

```
<%= raw qr_code.as_html %>
```

my controller is

```
qr_code = RQRCode::QRCode.new(device_id)
```

It renders  the `QR code` successfully. But, while printing the page, my `QR code` disappear. Is there any other way to display it?

Comment: Have you tried rendering it as `png`

Comment: What browsers? What HTML does it generate?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is while giving `ctrl+p`, we should check the background grapichs option to render the  `qr code`. silly of me